# spinner unusable and misdisplayed

Tags: android, layout, spinner

When I first launch my app everything displays and works correctly but when I close and reopen it a spinner and button that sit next to each other at the top of my relative layout are only about half of their usual height and the spinner is unusable. If I click it nothing drops down (but the button works as usual). Other elements below the spinner and but display as usual.

I spent half the day googling and playing with the app code and layout XML and have made little to no progress.

Anyone got a clue as to what could be causing this? It only happens on subsequent runs of the app.

Here is the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/namespinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/namespinner"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/namespinner"
    android:onClick="onEditButtonPressed"
    android:text="@string/dob_edit" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondsDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="@string/seconds"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minutesDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondsDisplay"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="@string/minutes"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hoursDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/minutesDisplay"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:text="@string/hours"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hourstext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/hoursDisplay"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hoursDisplay"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/daystext"
    android:text="@string/hours_lable"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dayDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/hoursDisplay"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="@string/days"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/daystext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dayDisplay"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/namespinner"
    android:text="@string/days_lable"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minutesText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minutesDisplay"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minutesDisplay"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hourstext"
    android:text="@string/minutes_lable"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondstext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/secondsDisplay"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secondsDisplay"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/minutesText"
    android:text="@string/seconds_lable"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

This should be the relevant parts of the main activity that call it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static Spinner nameSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter nameAdapter;
    static ArrayList nameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

        // get spinner and init array if needed
        if (nameList == null) {
            nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namespinner);
            nameList = new ArrayList();
            nameList.add("( Add )");
        }

        // populate spinner
        nameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, nameList);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(nameAdapter);

        // listen for events/selections on the spinner
        nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView,
            View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // read state
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {
            // do I want to do anything here?
        }

        });
    }
}
```

Edited to clean up the code display and add the class def. and class variables.

Comment: For the starter, post your layout XML, `Activity` code, and custom adapter for the spinner (if there is)

Comment: Post your code. It's very relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added some code earlier, I was just unsure what exactly to post.
I just tried wrapping the spinner and button in a linearlayout but it end in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the spinner in an if statement that didn't really have anything to do with setting the spinner was the cause of the problem. By changing this:

```
if (nameList == null) {
        nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namespinner);
        nameList = new ArrayList();
        nameList.add("( Add )");
}
```

to

```
nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namespinner);
if (nameList == null) {
        nameList = new ArrayList();
        nameList.add("( Add )");
}
```

got it sorted.

A good nights sleep and fresh eyes where all that were needed. :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the code wrote in the onresume method in oncreate method!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't effect the running of the program. I'm really at a lose for what could be causing this behaviour. Why does it work perfectly the first time but not after that? What could be changing?